If the person presses Enter, I need the error not to appear like this. I need a specific message to appear, for example
If the person presses Enter, I need the error not to appear like this. I need a specific message to appear, for example

print(table)
print()
print('1 - Download All Episodes')
print()
print('2 - Download Specific Episodes')
print()
print('3 - Next Shows')
print()
print('4 - Enter Link')
choice = int(input('Enter Your Choice: '))
print(table)

choice = int(input('Enter Your Choice: '))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Press any key to continue . . .


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you learnt about exceptions? Now would be the time to do so, if not. In doing so, you should learn about try and except.

Accept the input as a plain string and check if it is empty, before calling int().

@JohnGordon but that only covers one of many potential problems; it's an example of a LBYL approach.  Python masters prefer EAFP.
